# How to add custom command in in declaration in tiptap when extending existing extension when using typescript

Tags: typescript, tiptap

I am trying to extend table extension from tiptap and add an additional command.

```
declare module '@tiptap/core' {
  interface Commands<ReturnType> {
    table: {
      setTableClassName: () => ReturnType;
    };
  }
}
export const CustomTable = Table.extend({
  addAttributes() {}, 
  addCommands() {}
})
```

When i add the above code i get the following error

```
Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'table' must be of type '{ insertTable: (options?: { rows?: number | undefined; cols?: number | undefined; withHeaderRow?: boolean | undefined; } | undefined) => ReturnType; addColumnBefore: () => ReturnType; ... 16 more ...; setCellSelection: (position: { ...; }) => ReturnType; }', but here has type '{ setTableClassName: () => ReturnType; }'.ts(2717)
table.d.ts(14, 9): 'table' was also declared here.
```

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Can you share how you are extending the existing `Table` extension ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur Thank you for replying back. I have updated the question with how I am extending the Table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue I think it is because table is already used, try to change `table` in declare to your own name e.g. `customTable` and then set the name in the function CustomTable

```js
declare module '@tiptap/core' {
  interface Commands<ReturnType> {
    customTable: {
      setTableClassName: () => ReturnType;
    };
  }
}
export const CustomTable = Table.extend({
  name: "customTable",
  addAttributes() {}, 
  addCommands() {}
})
```

Remember that your table nodes now will have the name "customTable"